# copy text to diodon/clipboard on boot

Tags: command-line, copy, paste

How can I copy text to diodon/clipboard from terminal command? I work frequently in norwegian with is not my native language, so I would like to always have norwegian letters in my diodon to simply paste them.

Answer (score 0):

There is similar question in [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/diodon/+question/222227), which says (@2013) that this is not possible.

As this does not work, I suggest to install Norwegian keyboard layout and  use shortcut to switch between layouts. I use it (for Russian) all the time. If you use standard Ubuntu, there is default shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and it is very convienient for me.